# Palindrome Code

Tags: python, python-2.7, palindrome

I had a internship interview today and they asked for me to talk about how I would determine whether a string is a palindrome or not using python. I set out my basic structure and some pseudocode and that all went just fine... Now that I'm home, I wanted to actually write the code.

Everything is in place, and I do a comparison of each letter in the string to determine whether or not it is a palindrome. The code works, I just have one small problem. The way I have it structured, it outputs 'The string, ~whatever~, is NOT a Palindrome.' for every single letter comparison until the last one, where it will output the final determination of whether it is a Palindrome or not.

I get why this is happening but I'm kind of stuck on how to fix it. Can someone please guide me on how to fix the if statements in my code below so it will only output whether or not it is a palindrome once?

```
string = raw_input('Enter your string here: ')
sa = list(string)
n = len(sa)
if n%2 == 0:
    print('This string has an even number of letters.')
    for x in range(0, n/2):
        if sa[x] == sa[n/2 - x]:
            print('The string, ' + string + ', is a palindrome!')
        else:
            print('The string, ' + string + ', is NOT a palindrome!')
else:
    print('This string has an odd number of letters.')
    a = int(n/2)
    for x in range(0, a):
        if sa[x] == sa[n - a]:
            print('The string, ' + string + ', is a palindrome!')
        else:
            print('The string, ' + string + ', is NOT a palindrome!')
```

Some examples of the output if I run the code are:

```
Enter your string here: abba
This string has an even number of letters.
The string, abba, is NOT a palindrome!
The string, abba, is a palindrome!

Enter your string here: racecar
This string has an odd number of letters.
The string, racecar, is NOT a palindrome!
The string, racecar, is NOT a palindrome!
The string, racecar, is a palindrome!

Enter your string here: travel
This string has an even number of letters.
The string, travel, is NOT a palindrome!
The string, travel, is NOT a palindrome!
The string, travel, is NOT a palindrome!
```

Also, if you have any recommendations on how to improve the code, please don't hesitate to send them my way. I've stayed away from other examples because I wanted this attempt to be organic, and from me.

Comment: You need to save whether the string is a palindrome or not in a variable, and output it once at the end of the script. Also, silly question - why not just go something like `print string, "is" if string[::-1] == string else "is not", "a palindrome"`?

Comment: You're printing at every iteration of your for loop. What did you expect?

Comment: Ahh! So right after the if statement, I could do something like: answer = "The string is a palindrome." Then at the end, I could say print(answer)?

Faris Sbahi, I know... I wrote at the beginning of my post that I knew why it was happening, just not a way to fix it.

Comment: This is a common beginner mistake, but I usually see it in programs that are searching a list for something. They always put an `else` clause when the item doesn't match, but you can't know whether a search failed until you reach the end.

Comment: Why are you comparing with `sa[n/2 - x]`? That's only checking if the first half of the string is a palindrome, not if the whole string is a palindrome.

Comment: shadow, definitely not a silly question... A great suggestion. Barmar, yeah, I just caught that error when it told me that 'fred' is a palindrome ha ha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the most direct way of salvaging your code:

```
string = raw_input('Enter your string here: ')
sa = list(string)
n = len(sa)
palindrome = True
if n%2 == 0:
    print('This string has an even number of letters.')
    for x in range(0, n/2):
        if sa[x] != sa[n - x - 1]:
            palindrome = False
else:
    print('This string has an odd number of letters.')
    a = int(n/2)
    for x in range(0, a):
        if sa[x] != sa[n - x - 1]:
            palindrome = False

if palindrome:
    print 'The string, ' + string + ', is a palindrome!'
else:
    print 'The string, ' + string + ', is NOT a palindrome!'
```

First off, you don't want to report on whether it's a palindrome or not each time you check a character pair. Assume that it's a palindrome with a boolean variable and change it to False if you discover otherwise.

Next, there were a few problems with your loops and indexing. In your even case, you should be counting back from the end of the string, not the middle. Likewise, in your odd case, you should be counting back with respect to your loop variable `x`, rather than the static midpoint. In both cases, you'll have to adjust your index by one to avoid errors when `x = 0`.

Finally, while the approach you've taken is a good way to do it manually, there are far more concise methods you can use that are built in to the language. Simply comparing the input string against `reversed(string)` or `string[::-1]` will yield a boolean containing the answer to whether it's a palindrome or not.

Comment: You're awesome, thank you! Yeah, the challenge was to do it manually. I initially just told them I would check the string reversed, but they said to do it as if there were no preexisting methods built into the language. More just testing problem solving skills. I would give you an upvote but I'm still new here and don't have that 15 rep. :/

Comment: You're welcome! In the context of an interview, that definitely all makes sense. Hope it went well.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, you might have to fix some syntax as I am not a Python dev. :)

```
string = raw_input('Enter your string here: ')
sa = list(string)
n = len(sa)

bool isPalindrome =false

if n%2 == 0:
    print('This string has an even number of letters.')
    for x in range(0, n/2):
        if sa[x] == sa[n/2 - x]:
            isPalindrome = true
        else:
            //should be in a block        
            isPalindrome = false
            break;
else:
    print('This string has an odd number of letters.')
    a = int(n/2)
    for x in range(0, a):
        if sa[x] == sa[n - a]:
            isPalindrome = true
        else:
            //should be in a block        
            isPalindrome = false
            break;


 if isPalindrome:
            print('The string, ' + string + ', is a palindrome!')
 else:
            print('The string, ' + string + ', is NOT a palindrome!')
```

Comment: The problem is that you are displaying the messages for every check rather than displaying the message once after all the checks are complete.

Comment: Thank you! Yeah, I knew that was the problem, I was just having a block on how to fix it. This is why I come to you guys. StackOverflow is bae.

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of a flag during the iterations. Assign it as `True` at the start, then  `False` later when you test for a letter that doesn't work.

Or better yet, maybe something like this would simplify things a bit:

```
string = 'nurses run'.replace(' ','') 
gnirts = string[::-1]
if all( [ a==b for a,b in zip(string,gnirts) ] ):
    print("It's a palindrome.")
else:
    print("It's not a palindrome.")
```

Comment: Thank you, Brian. This is a really clean version... Mine looks like a mess lol.

Comment: The replace operation, is there a different syntax for 2.7? If I change my code to be: string = raw_input('Enter your string here: ').replace(' ', ''), or string.replace(' ', ''), it starts giving me wrong answers...

Comment: I'm not aware of a difference, and it works the same for a few test strings I just tried in 3.4 and 2.7. Is there a specific one you have that's behaving unexpectedly?

Comment: I'm just trying to get my code to work for phrases, like the one you gave. If I enter 'dont nod' as my string, it is outputting that it's not a palindrome even with an if statement saying: if (' ' in string): string.replace(' ', '').

Comment: `'dont nod'.replace(' ','')` gives the expected result of `'dontnod'`, so look through the logic in your code. The other posters mentioned some of those issues. Try just `'dontnod'` if you don't trust it :)

Comment: Ahh, I figured it out, just the logic as usual. Thank you! if (' ' in string) == True: string = string.replace(' ', ''), this ended up working. Now just a few more anomalies to work out... It's telling me that 'collin' is a palindrome... Ugh.